# Oracle sql missing expression

Tags: group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Oracle SQL query and running the query, it gives ORA-00936: missing expression.  When I hover over the red in Oracle Sql Developer, it says "Syntax Error. Partially Recognized Rules, railroad diagrams. I think there's something wrong with my Group By.  I think Group by needs to have all query columns in it, but I know the last 3 are min/max/avg, so I don't think it makes sense to add those to the group by separately.  What is the proper way to add them to the group by?

```
 select        
    do.dcode,
    ds.SERIALNO,  
    ds.BASECOMPONENTCODE,
    TO_CHAR (strt.DLOCALECRTDT,'MON') as MON,--this looks like 13-OCT-15 05.19.03.000000000 PM
    Max (do.METRICVALUE)  as MaxCount,   
    min (do.METRICVALUE)  as MinCount,
    avg (do.METRICVALUE)  as AvgCount

          FROM
            TECH_DWH.D_DIM_OUTPUTCOUNT_TBL do
             join (
                     Select d1.dcode,d1.organizationid
                     from  K_D_VW d1
                     where
                    d1.isactive='Y'
         and d1.organizationid = 7500 -- company id
                    ) d on d.dcode=do.dcode
             left join
            TECH_DWH.D_COMPSTAT_SERIAL_NO_MAP_TBL csm on csm.DCOMPONENTSTATEID = do.DCOMPONENTSTATEID
             join TECH_D.D_DIM_SERIAL_NO_TBL  ds on ds.serialnoid = csm.serialnoid
             left join TECH_DWH.d_dim_medianumber_tbl dm on dm.DCOMPONENTSTATEID = csm.DCOMPONENTSTATEID
    left join TECH_DWH.D_DEVICE_COMPSTATE_STRT_TBL strt on strt.DCOMPONENTSTATEID = csm.DCOMPONENTSTATEID

           WHERE
           instr(upper(ds.basecomponentcode),'PRINT')>0  AND --- return only device components
            LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE((do.METRICVALUE), ' +-.0123456789',' '))) is null -- test for only rows with numberic metrivalue's
     AND do.dcode like '0046'
    AND strt.COMPONENTSTATECODE like '%EP_DEVICE%'
            and strt.DLOCALECRTDT >= to_date ( '30-12-2021', 'DD-MM-YYYY' )
            and 
            Group by  --red squiggly at "by", but error line number is following line
             do.dcode,
    ds.SERIALNO,  
    ds.BASECOMPONENTCODE,
    TO_CHAR(strt.DLOCALECRTDT,'MON'),
    do.METRICVALUE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's obvious, is

```
and 
    Group by  --red squiggly at "by", but error line number is following line
     do.dcode,
```

What's that `AND` doing alone? Remove it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that.  there were comments between the and, and the group by so I missed it.  I appreciate it.  :)